# Unresponsive pdf viewer in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, windows, viewers, adobe

I have been using TexMaker for a while now and I am quite satisfied overall. For the past few days though, the  external pdf viewer does not seem to be working. When I click on the icon, which is the second icon on the top right next to the tick, nothing happens. I suspect that the latest adobe update messed up the settings somehow but I don't know specifically which ones. I was wondering then, is anyone else experiencing the same issue? If so, how can we overcome it?

[image]

Comment: I have no problem, if I select first  `external viewer` in the Configuration options.

Comment: @Bernard Hi, thanks for your comment. When I choose `external viewer` and click on View PDF in the main screen afterwards, I get the error, `Error : could not start the command : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" "filename".pdf`. where filename is the name of that document. Is that related?

Comment: The path to the latest update is now `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader`. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @Bernard That works, thank you very much. Feel free to post the updated path as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: OK, I'll do it. But, if I may, why do you use Adobe Reader? If you want an external viewer, SumatraPDF is much lighter, faster and it doesn't lock the pdfs.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I'll take a look on Sumatra. I have been too busy to optimize the settings and the programs so far.

Comment: SumatraPDF for Windows systems is the reference : the whole program uses … < 11Mb,  works with .synctex files for forward and inverse search, and has a 64 bits version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the last update, Adobe Reader is `Acrobat Reader` again and the path to the executable is now:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader
```

Comment: I have the same problem but unfortunately this solution doesn't work. Are there suggestions?

Comment: @Vincenzo Zaccaro: Yes. One should not use Acrobat Reader for TeX files: .pdfs are locked and you must think of closing them before recompiling. If you're under Windows, the best choice is SumatraPDF: ultra-fast, ultra-light (12Mo installed vs 284 Mo!), exists in 64 bits version, and above all, has direct and inverse search capabilities, which Acrobat Reader has not.

Comment: Some more details: go to `Configure -> External Viewer` and enter the path: `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf`

Comment: @AaronVoelker A point though : with the internal viewer, compiling and opening the pdf and recompiling works like a charm, somewhere the interval viewer let go of the pdf file so that `pdflatex` can use. It doesnt't seem to be the case with for instance acrobat reader, leading to "i cant' write on file 'blah.pdf'" in texmaker for instance. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Contrary to Acrobat Reader, Sumatrapdf doesn't lock the .pdf.

Comment: I too face the same problem. Just reset the setting in TeXmaker. Its working properly.

Answer (score 0):

With Adobe update my case was solved using this path:

"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat DC/Acrobat/Acrobat.exe" %.pdf

Built-in Viewer and Embed were flagged.